# Able to bypass Image validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have wrapped an executable inside an image which has the following content -

```
GIF89a<?php
echo 'hacked';
?>
```

and saved it as filename *image.gif*.

Now when I upload this image then it's able to bypass the **image** and **dimension** validation.

`'photo' => 'required|image|dimensions:min_width=20,min_height=20',`

Is there a way to validate this kind of images?

A workaround I have tried -

Used PHP function `getimagesize()` but it returns

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => 16188
  1 => 26736
  2 => 1
  3 => "width="16188" height="26736""
  "channels" => 3
  "mime" => "image/gif"
]
```

although image is not valid but still it has valid *width* and *height*.

Comment: Since apache only executes files that have php extension at the end of them, hacking a website with this is unless you have code that allows local file inclusion. Having a gif with php code in it is no different from log poisoning attack.

Comment: Totally agree with you on this, but my question is how to validate the image. I have tried the same image to upload on different services and all of them detect it as a harmful content.

Comment: Instead of getimagesize() have you tried using exif_imagetype() ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php

Comment: @Andreas `exif_imagetype()` is returning `1`. NO LUCK.

Answer (score 2):

As [this article](http://giflib.sourceforge.net/whatsinagif/bits_and_bytes.html) informs, a GIF file has a header field, followed by dimensions. What you've made has bytes that are valid in the dimensions part, and thus will get parsed as dimensions. This is incomplete for verifying a GIF imposer. You'd need to do a more in-depth analysis of the GIF bytes to make sure it doesn't contain a harmful payload.

Comment: Thanks for the article. I have tried the same image to upload on different services and also with a different extension (.jpg, .jpeg) but all of them detect it as a harmful content. So my question is how can I achieve the same with `Laravel`?